# Querying Couchbase using N1QL

Tags: f#, couchbase, sql++

I can query docs using views just fine, but switching to N1QL gives me Success property as false. What went wrong ?

```
    let cluster = new Cluster()
    let bucket = cluster.OpenBucket("mydoc","")
    let query = """SELECT * FROM mydoc where SET = 'SET24MM2SCLV01'"""
    let result = bucket.Query(query)
    Console.WriteLine(result.Success) //would give false
```

Comment: Did you try to run the query directly, eg using cbq? Does it succeed? Does it return an error message?

Comment: BTW `SET` is a keyword in N1QL. Trying to use it in a query returns a syntax error. Do your `mydoc` documents actually have a `SET` property?

Comment: I'm porting the db from mongodb :) so..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SET` is a [reserved word](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.0/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/reservedwords.html) in N1QL. In order to use it as an identifier, you need to escape it with backticks, eg:

```
SELECT * FROM mydoc where `SET` = 'SET24MM2SCLV01'
```

If you don't you'll get a syntax error:

```
"errors": [
    {
        "code": 3000,
        "msg": "syntax error - at SET"
    }
]
```

You should change your query to

<strike>let query = """SELECT * FROM mydoc where `SET` = 'SET24MM2SCLV01'"""</strike>

```
let query = "SELECT * FROM mydoc where `SET` = 'SET24MM2SCLV01'"
```

**EDIT**

The query result [also contains](http://docs.couchbase.com/developer/dotnet-2.0/n1ql-queries.html) an `Error` property with the errors that occured in the query. This should be checked always if `Success` returns false. If the query fails even after escaping `SET`, this will explain what other error prevents the query from running.

For example, I just noticed that the entire query is enclosed in double quotes. This would send a string literal to the server instead of a query.

Comment: I had the key name changed to something else but still couldnt get the query to run. Btw how do i do it from "cbq" ?

Comment: The result also contains an `Error` property. Check it to see what the actual error is. `cbq` is the command-line tool for Couchbase. If you can't use it, just use any tools you have to execute queries, so that you can check the error messages. Without knowing what's wrong, you can't fix it.

Comment: @himekami A more serious problem - you enclosed the query in quotes, converting it to a string literal instead of a query.

Comment: Thank you so much. I used the cbq tool as you suggested and i got this error code 4000. So i got the primary index key defined. Then when i tested using the cbq again the return result was successful. I've also changed the query literal as suggested. Works great. TQ!